# Passing a variable between javascript and embedded java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, web-services

I'm running a web service and calling a method by embedding the java inside the script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSS(){
<%-- start web service invocation --%>

var x = <%
try {
    org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS_Service service = new
    org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS_Service();
    org.me.testbilling.TestBillingWS port = service.getTestBillingWSPort();

    java.lang.String name = "Mike" ;

    java.lang.String result = port.getSS(name);
    out.println(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {
   out.println(ex);
}
%>
<%-- end web service invocation --%>

    alert(x);
        }
    </script>
```

The issue is that I want this line:

```
java.lang.String name = "Mike";
```

To be dynamic, so that it can pull a variable from text the user entered, or a selection like this:

```
<select id="getName" onchange="getSS($('#getName').find(":selected").text())">
<option>Mike</option>
<option>John</option>
<option>Patty</option>
<option>Stephanie</option>
</select>
```

So what I need is either a better way to make that call, or a way to pass the variable dynamically into that script. Any suggestions?

Comment: It just doesn't work that way. The Javascript is running on the client, while the Java code is running on the server. Even though they're in the same file (which is bad style), they're a network connection away from each other.

Comment: So how can I call the java code and pass variables to it dynamically?

Comment: You need to make a request to the server. I'd recommend you go through some basic servlet tutorials, stop including Java code inside JSPs and forget about trying to make webservices just yet. You're missing all the basics.

Comment: I already did a servlet tutorial. It *seems* to go in the opposite direction I want. From what I can tell it writes the HTML page itself, but that won't get me to pass a variable based on user input to the java code (without reloading the page) anyway.

Comment: I am using this tutorial: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

Comment: So you did one servlet tutorial and now you think you know how servlets work. Well, the code in your question is horrible and wrong, and you'll never get it working. Don't include Java scriptlets inside JSP. Make a servlet direct to a JSP, so you can use at least JSTL inside it. Then it'll make it clearer what's happening on the client side and what's on the server side.

Comment: I don't think I know servlets intimately. That's why I specifically said that it only "seemed" to go in the opposite direction I wanted to go in, which wasn't to say that servlets were bad or useless, only that I had concerns that it would accomplish my specific goal and I wanted to make that concern clear, which is why I included the tutorial page so as to make it easy for others to make sense out of my confusion. Right now I'm in the process of doing what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is on client machine, but your java is on server.

If you want to send data from client to server, you need to use jQuery.ajax to send.

See this link http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: link only answer is not encouraged in SO